# Height of ListView not correctly set

Tags: android, listview

I'm having some issues with setting my ListView's height.
My `ListView` is inside a `ScrollView` and it's populated with some elements. In order to have my `ListView` expanded I programmatically calculate the height of the elements and set the `ListView` height accordingly.
For some reasons it's like my measures are not correct.
Here's my `ListView` item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    android:tint="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="12dp"
    />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_trailer_item_title"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:padding="12dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my piece of code for setting the `ListView` height:

```
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

    TrailersAdapter listAdapter = (TrailersAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int elements = listAdapter.getCount();
    Log.d("AAA","Got " + elements + " elements");

    if (elements>0) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(0, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0,0);
        //get the height of a single item, multiply by the number of items and get the total height for the items
        int totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight() * elements;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();

        //calculate the total height summing the height of the dividers too
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount()-1));

        //set the height
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Heres how the Activity looks like:
[image: top]
[image: botton]
The trailers should be five, but only 4 are shown (in other cases half is shown)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should never use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`! [Google talk](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf) pag. 47.

Comment: if I expand it it's not scrollable, so this should not be a problem. What do you suggest to have a dynamically populated list of items expanded inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: Both `ListView` and `ScrollView` are scrollable by definition. I don't understand what you are trying to do, but nesting two scrolling components is for sure the wrong approach.

Comment: I have a `ScrollView` with an image and some `TextView`s, and a list of trailers. Everything's size is not known a priori, and the list of trailers is dynamically populated with the previously written item layout. The list is expanded at its maximum and there should be nothing to scroll, since everything scrolls with the `ScrollView`. I'm providing you with an image

Comment: ok I've added some screenshots

Comment: Then, IMHO, you should add items dynamically in you `ScrollView` attaching them to it. Or, you can treat the upper part as an header of the `ListView` so that you don't need a `ScrollView` anymore.

Comment: Try to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` replace `ScrollView`, and remember `android:fillViewport="true"`. It 's a workaround, and affect in some case.

Comment: does not change anything...